# AWK - using substr integer as part of if condition

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, integer, substr

I'm attempting to use awk one liner to print lines of a file in which the substring is less than a defined variable. Also the line must start with the letter E. The E condition is working, but not the result for the simple if 'less than' I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong here?? It is incorporated into a larger bash script. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
minimum_dpt=50

awk -v depth="$minimum_dpt" '{if (/^E/ && int(substr($0,65,6)<depth)) print "Shot: ",substr($0,21,5)," has depth below minimum. Value: ",substr($0,65,6)'}
```

Input:

```
E1985020687     1 1  2942984632.99S 88 354.60E 596044.16185585.10000.9 44 826 9
E1985020687     1 1  2943264732.95S 88 359.24E 595917.26185461.80000.5 44 82727
E1985020687     1 1  2944264741.97S 88 450.86E 594520.36185751.92445.3 44 82846
E1985020687     1 1  2945264741.97S 88 450.86E 594520.36185751.90045.3 44 82846
```

Output:

```
Shot:   2942  has depth below minimum. Value:  0000.9
Shot:   2943  has depth below minimum. Value:  0000.5
Shot:   2945  has depth below minimum. Value:  0045.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intended:

```
int(substr($0,65,6))<depth
```

or even just:

```
(substr($0,65,6)+0)<depth
```

instead of what you have:

```
int(substr($0,65,6)<depth)
```

There's probably a better way to do this but without seeing your input and output idk...

Comment: You're absolutely right Ed. Simple misplacement of the parentheses. It's working as expected now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Input / output fields added.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for the task like that:

```
$ cat input 
102030405060
102030405060
203050601070
904050308090
104030607040
406080903040
$ awk -v dpt=50 '/^1/ && (int(substr($0, 9, 2)) > int(dpt))' <input
104030607040
```

(edited according to Ed's comment, thanks ;)

Comment: UUOC and Useless `print $0`. Also - do you think `substr($0, 9, 2) > dpt` is doing a numeric or string comparison? Are you sure? Since you know what kind of comparison you NEED it to do, why not force it to do that?